# Debian Lenny 64 Bit doesn't show 4GB Memory

Tags: debian, memory, 64-bit

I'm using Debian 5.0 (Lenny) 64Bit on my server and my server has 4GB memory but unfortunately Debian shows 2 GB on /proc/meminfo and with "top" command. Do I need to use bigmem kernel with 64bit Debian?

Answer (score 1):

No. Debian x64 supports up to 64 Tb.
I use Debian 5.0 amd64(2.6.26-24lenny1)

```
cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:     12330948 kB
```

http://www.debian.org/ports/amd64/

Please, add output # lshw | grep "*-memory" -A 40